# SQL Self Join with no repetition

Tags: mysql, self-join

Employee table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname    | lname     | start_date | end_date | superior_emp_id | dept_id | title              | assigned_branch_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael  | Smith     | 2005-06-22 | NULL     |            NULL |       3 | President          |                  1 |
|      2 | Susan    | Barker    | 2006-09-12 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Vice President     |                  1 |
|      3 | Robert   | Tyler     | 2005-02-09 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Treasurer          |                  1 |
|      4 | Susan    | Hawthorne | 2006-04-24 | NULL     |               3 |       1 | Operations Manager |                  1 |
|      5 | John     | Gooding   | 2007-11-14 | NULL     |               4 |       2 | Loan Manager       |                  1 |
|      6 | Helen    | Fleming   | 2008-03-17 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  1 |
|      7 | Chris    | Tucker    | 2008-09-15 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      8 | Sarah    | Parker    | 2006-12-02 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      9 | Jane     | Grossman  | 2006-05-03 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2006-07-27 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  2 |
|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2004-10-23 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2007-01-08 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     13 | John     | Blake     | 2004-05-11 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  3 |
|     14 | Cindy    | Mason     | 2006-08-09 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     15 | Frank    | Portman   | 2007-04-01 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     16 | Theresa  | Markham   | 2005-03-15 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  4 |
|     17 | Beth     | Fowler    | 2006-06-29 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
|     18 | Rick     | Tulman    | 2006-12-12 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT e1.fname, e1.lname,
'VS' AS vs,
e2.fname, e2.lname
FROM employee e1
INNER JOIN employee e2
ON e1.emp_id < e2.emp_id
WHERE e1.title = "Teller" AND e2.title = "Teller";
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
| fname    | lname    | vs | fname    | lname    |
+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Sarah    | Parker   |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Jane     | Grossman |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Thomas   | Ziegler  |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Samantha | Jameson  |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Cindy    | Mason    |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Chris    | Tucker   | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Jane     | Grossman |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Thomas   | Ziegler  |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Samantha | Jameson  |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Cindy    | Mason    |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Sarah    | Parker   | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Thomas   | Ziegler  |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Samantha | Jameson  |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Cindy    | Mason    |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Jane     | Grossman | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Thomas   | Ziegler  | VS | Samantha | Jameson  |
| Thomas   | Ziegler  | VS | Cindy    | Mason    |
| Thomas   | Ziegler  | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Thomas   | Ziegler  | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Thomas   | Ziegler  | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Samantha | Jameson  | VS | Cindy    | Mason    |
| Samantha | Jameson  | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Samantha | Jameson  | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Samantha | Jameson  | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Cindy    | Mason    | VS | Frank    | Portman  |
| Cindy    | Mason    | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Cindy    | Mason    | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Frank    | Portman  | VS | Beth     | Fowler   |
| Frank    | Portman  | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
| Beth     | Fowler   | VS | Rick     | Tulman   |
+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
```

Intention:

I wanted to pair up people together as if employees were playing a chess game, where one employee will play against only one person in the first round not 3 or 4 different people. For example I don't want Chris Tucker playing against Sarah, Jane, Thomas... etc in the first round. I want him paired up with only one opponent. If he or his adversary looses they are out.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by randomly enumerating the names and then choosing them in pairs:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then fname end) as fname_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then lname end) as lname_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then fname end) as fname_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then lname end) as lname_2       
from (select e.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from employee e cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by rand()
     ) e
group by floor((seqnum - 1) / 2);
```

This assumes that you have an even number of employees, which seems to be implicitly assumed as part of the problem.

Comment: Ha! Worked like magic! Thanks. Query is very complex, though for me being a newbie. Will have to dissect it later.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Does this guarantee that the a person record will not be paired with itself? The requirement is to pair every person with another person.

Comment: @HashPsi . . . There is no way that a record could be paired with itself.  The rows are essentially being numbered, with the even numbers for the first name and the odd numbers for the second.